# Rename Assets when it is uploaded

Tags: craft3, assets, php

I would like to rename new assets by PHP, but somehow it does not work.
In Craft 3, I suppose it is like;

```
Event::on(\craft\services\Elements::class, \craft\services\Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) {
    if ($event->params['isNewAsset']) {
        $asset = $event->params['asset'];
        $folder_id = $asset->folderId;

        if ($folder_id == "22")
        {
            $filename = $asset->filename . "_test";
            craft()->assets->renameFile($asset, $filename);
        }
    }
});
```

My code is like that, but this message appears;

```
Upload failed. The error message was: “Getting unknown property: craft\events\ElementEvent::params
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `Craft 2` methods with `Craft 3` methods.
This will get the the assets extension with `$asset->getFilename(true)` and add `test_` in the beginning of the filename:

```
Event::on(
    \craft\services\Elements::class,
    \craft\services\Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(Event $event)   {
        $asset = $event->element;
        $folderId = $asset->getFolder();


        if ($event->isNew && $asset instanceof craft\elements\Asset && $folderId == '22') {
            $newName =  'test_' . $asset->getFilename(true);
            Craft::$app->assets->moveAsset($asset, $folderId, $newName);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, it works almost I would like to.

Actually, the function of getFolder() gets the folder as a string.
So I modified the function like this;

```
Event::on(\craft\services\Elements::class, \craft\services\Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(Event $event) {
    if ($event->element instanceof \craft\elements\Asset) {
        $asset = $event->element;
        $folder = $asset->getFolder();
        $folderId = $folder->id;

        if ($event->isNew && $folderId == '22') {
            $newName =  'test_' . $folderId . '_' . $asset->getFilename(true);
            Craft::$app->assets->moveAsset($asset, $folder, $newName);
        }
    }
});
```